# SQL Select user by time period everytime its status changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to retrieve information from a table which looks like

```
"ID"              "Type"             "Status"          "LAST_UPDATE" 
"123456"            "one"              "ACTIVE"          12/01/22 
"123456"            "one"              "DISABLED"        16/01/22 
"123456"            "one"              "ACTIVE"          19/01/22 
"234567"            "one"              "ACTIVE"          01/02/22 
"345678"            "two"              "DISABLED"        04/03/22
```

I want to select last_update ranges everytime the status changes to retrieve information like:

```
ID          date_range                    Status 
123456       12/01/22 - 16/01/22           "ACTIVE" 
123456       16/01/22 - 19/01/22           "DISABLED"
```

For every ID.

The only step I succeeded to do is to get the status for every user last_update with:

```
SELECT a.* FROM user_table a WHERE a.LAST_UPDATE = (SELECT MAX(b.LAST_UPDATE)
                                                    FROM user_table b
                                                    WHERE b.id = a.id
                                                    ORDER BY b.id DESC
                                                    LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Thanks I didn't add at first because I didn't want to get T-sql solution ;) added now

Comment: You've tagged as SQL Server so that comment makes no sense, as does your use of `limit` in your example query - both because that's not SQL Server and it has no effect as `max` returns a single row without a group by.

Comment: I know that limit doesn't make sense, it was for test purpose. Max could return multiple row if last_update date is duplicate, I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 b.LAST_UPDATE 
    FROM user_table b 
    WHERE b.LAST_UPDATE > a.LAST_UPDATE 
      AND a.ID = b.ID 
    ORDER BY LAST_UPDATE asc
  ) 
FROM
  user_table a
```

Using it here you get the data you want. If you do not want null entry then please add condition.